# Azure Functions proxy as a router

Tags: azure-functions

I have a number of proxies defined as simple redirects, but I have one that has a chain of requests. It seems to be ignoring some of the parameters. The link raw, looks like this:

http://www.myWebsite.com/signout?fromURI=http://www.anotherwebsite.com?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://www.anotherwebsite.com/secondtask?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://finaldestination.com/Home

I have tried the following:

```
  "proxyLogout": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/site/redirect"
      },
      "backendUri": "http://www.myWebsite.com/signout",
      "requestOverrides": {
        "backend.request.querystring.fromURI": "http://www.anotherwebsite.com?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://www.anotherwebsite.com/secondtask?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://finaldestination.com/Home"
      }
    }
```

But I suspect it's stopping at the first query param in the "fromURI". I also have 2 post_logout_redirect_uri parameters.
Any ideas how I get it to route to my full url?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work in the end - seemed my scenario was too complicated or not what the proxies.json was intended for.
In the end I had to create a simple HTTPTrigger function that did a permanent 302 redirect to my new destination.